# can hadoop and Sqoop run separately on different machines

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hadoop2, sqoop2

I have installed sqoop 1.4.6 on new node and hadoop is running on different node. Can i point my sqoop server to use existing hadoop environment ?

I know there is some argument "--hadoop-mapred-home" to set hadoop path but this is used within same node.

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop doesn't need all the hadoop services to be running locally. It just need a hadoop client. Install hadoop client, set HADOOP_HOME, add the same config files as that of the hadoop node.